# Missing .dylib library while opening in Xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios, xcode7

After downloading Xcode-7 beta, i opened the current project in Xcode 7.But all the dynamic libraries(.dylib) used in my code where shown as missing.

[image: Missing libraries]

Then i removed these libraries and try to add through Build Phase-> "Link Binary with Libraries".But it shows the .tbd extension file with same name.(eg. libs.dylib)
[image]

Is it any problem to use these extension instead of .dylib? My application were supported from iOS 7 to later.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually have an issue when building and running the app?

Comment: Yes,it is working fine in simulator even if it shows missing libraries in frame work folder.

Comment: Don't worry about it then.  All that stuff goes into my *Products* group in Xcode which is always closed.  I never see that red writing.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/39rcby/ios_9_os_x_1011_xcode_7_development_with_dynamic/ this link helps me

Comment: I asked you if you actually had a build error and you replied that you did not.  That link you provide is a method to resolve build errors, so it does not apply to your situation.

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724799/dylib-file-is-missing

Answer (score 3):

I also have same issue but After updating My Mac **OS X Yosemite** to OS X **El Capitan** then that issue solved by using `.tbd extension` file with same name.

Actually In the Xcode 7, There are no more dynamic binary libraries (.dylib) instead of it offer .tbd libraries and I think that may be recognised by OS X El Capitan & OS X El Capitan has support for the .tbd (file extension), which is not available with OS X Yosemite?

So the project that has (`.dylib`) can run only in the lower version of Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the references to the `.dylib` files and added the libraries back in as `.tbd` files. This seems to be working for me.