# .dylib file is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, dylib

I am trying to compile my project in iOS 9. I am using XCode7.
Here is how it looks like:
error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libiconv.dylib (No such file or directory)
```

My dylib files shows in red color so i tried to add it again but the is no dylib files, all the files are shown in `.tbd` instead of `.dylib`. Please help me on this..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*At last i fixed it*.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4572.
Add the dylib files into "Other Linker Flags".

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how this fixes the issue?

Comment: Its not my personal findings.. its from apple developer forums

Comment: @Jio for libxml2.dylib what exactly i need to add ??

Comment: You need to add -lxml2

Comment: Any idea how to add these flags via cmakelists ?

Answer (score 16):

Here's what worked for me.

1. Go into your Targets, Build Phases, "Link Binary with libraries", and click on the + button.

[image]

2. Click on the "Add other..." button

[image]

3. Hit CMD+Shift+G to open the "Go to folder" dialog, and cut'n'paste the folder:  `/usr/lib`

[image]

4. In the top-right search box, type in a section of your "missing" file, which for me, was `libsqlite3.dylib`, then click on Open.

[image]

This should link in the file which was previously missing.

(Tested with Xcode 7.1)

Answer (score 4):

Remove it from "Link Binary with Libraries" fixed my error.

Answer (score 1):

libz.dylib is now found under libz.tbd

the .tbd files are new "text-based stub libraries", that provide a much more compact version of the stub libraries for use in the SDK

see  [Swift 2 / iOS 9 - libz.dylib not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30815806/swift-2-ios-9-libz-dylib-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the libc++..tbd framework to your project. And compile again.[image]

Also try to add libiconv.dylib to your project frameworks.

Comment: error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk/usr/lib/libc++.tbd is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

Comment: are you trying to integrate any other SDK into your project ? Or is it just a plain code template ?

Comment: i am trying to integrate my own library to this project..  Both having .dylib libraries.

Comment: Hi fixed it... https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4572. Add the dylib files into "Other Linker Flags". Thanks Mr.T for the support

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by:

Go to Your Target --> Build phases --> Link Binary With Libraries --> Add libiconv.dylib

That's All!