# while running my old project in ios 9.1 its showing this error.iPhoneOS9.1.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (No such file or directory)

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, facebook-sdk-4.0, ios9.1

i am using ios 9.1 xcode 7.1 but when i run my old project on my device its showing this error.

> error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   can't open file:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
>   (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

It was renamed `libsqlite3.tbd`.

Add this instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem after upgrading Xcode.

I've described the solution, step-by-step, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724799/dylib-file-is-missing/35364706#35364706).